# SQL Function in column running slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, function

I have a `computed column`(function) that is causing one of my tables to be extremely slow (its output is a column in my table. I thought it might be some logical statements in my function. I commented those out and just returned a string called `'test'`. This still caused the table to be slow. I believe the `SELECT` statement is slowing down the function. When I comment out the select statement, everything is cherry. I think I am not using functions in the correct manner.

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Pend_Type](@Suspense_ID int, @Loan_ID nvarchar(10),@Suspense_Date datetime, @Investor nvarchar(10))
RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Closing_Date Datetime, @Paid_Date Datetime
DECLARE @pendtype nvarchar(20)

--This is the issue!!!!
SELECT @Closing_Date = Date_Closing, @Paid_Date = Date_Paid from TABLE where Loan_ID = @Loan_ID

SET @pendtype = 'test'

--commented out logic

RETURN @pendtype
END
```

UPDATE:

I have another `computed column` that does something similar and is a column in the same table. This one runs fast. Anyone see a difference in why this would be?

```
Declare @yOrn AS nvarchar(1)
IF((Select count(suspense_ID) From TABLE where suspense_ID = @suspenseID) = 0)
SET @yOrn = 'N'
ELSE
SET @yOrn = 'Y'
RETURN @yOrn
```

Comment: do you have index on Loan_ID?

Answer (score 3):

You have isolated the performance problem in the `select` statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Closing_Date = Date_Closing, @Paid_Date = Date_Paid
from TABLE
where Loan_ID = @Loan_ID;
```

To make this run faster, create a composite index on `table(Load_id, Date_Closing, Date_Paid)`.

By the way, you are using `top` with no `order by`.  When multiple rows match, you can get any one of them back.  Normally, `top` is used with `order by`.

EDIT:

You can create the index by issuing the following command:

```
create index idx_table_load_closing_paid on table(Load_id, Date_Closing, Date_Paid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Gordon. I've never created an index before. What is their purpose?

Comment: Also, when doing a this select statement outside of the function, it's performance is 0 secs

Comment: @KyleCopeland . . . The index should make it much faster to find one of the rows you are looking for.  Because you are running the function inside a query, the performance may be affected by other things.

Comment: I am running at a column in a table. When I do a basic select statement it becomes sluggish. If I execute the function on one value it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax on creating an index. It looks like I cannot create one because we are using a view for that table.

Comment: @KyleCopeland . . . You need to talk to someone who understands your environment and has permissions to do things like adding an index.  There is probably a simple index that will improve performance a lot; you need someone local who has a bit more knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar functions are often executed like cursors, one row at a time; that is why they are slow and are to be avoided. I would not use the function as written but would write a set-based version instead.  incidentally a select top 1 without an order by column will not always give you the same record and is generally a poor practice. In this case I would think you would want the latest date for instance or the earliest one.

In this particular case I think you would be better off not using a function but using a derived table join.

Comment: HLGEM can you please share a little more on derived table joins. I've never heard of them before. Why are the beneficial?